# Target audiences column on a list made required not working

Tags: sharepoint-server, audience-targeting

I made the target audiences column in a list to required. but when I add a new list item without specifying the audience , it still gets created. When I edit the item, the target audiences field has a GUID in place generated automatically. Why is this happening? Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, unfortunately, SharePoint by default fills this field with the text "No targeting" when it's left empty which causes it to pass the required validation part.

[image]

If you want to make sure that Audience field is set as required, you need to write custom code in the newform/editform in the `PreSaveAction` method. Just edit the page and add a script editor/content editor webpart on it.

Code would be something like below:

```
function PreSaveAction(){

    var AudienceField = $('.ms-inputuserfield[title=Audience Editor]');
            if(AudienceField.html() === ''){
                $(AudienceField).append('<p class="ErrorMSG" style="color:red;">You must specify a value for the above required field</p>')
    return false;

            } else {
                return true;
            }
}
```

You can also take a look at JSlink to make sure its required. Code would be like below:

```
mjh.MyCustomFieldValidator = function () {
  mjh.MyCustomFieldValidator.prototype.Validate = function (value) {
    var isError = false;
    var errorMessage = "";

    if (value == "No Tageting") {
      isError = true;
      errorMessage = "Target Audience cant be empty";
    }
    return new SPClientForms.ClientValidation.ValidationResult(isError, errorMessage);
  };
};




var formCtx = SPClientTemplates.Utility.GetFormContextForCurrentField(ctx);

// register the field validators
var fieldValidators = new SPClientForms.ClientValidation.ValidatorSet();

if (formCtx.fieldSchema.Required) {
  fieldValidators.RegisterValidator(
    new SPClientForms.ClientValidation.RequiredValidator()
  );
} fieldValidators.RegisterValidator(new mjh.MyCustomFieldValidator());

formCtx.registerValidationErrorCallback(formCtx.fieldName, mjh.onError);
formCtx.registerClientValidator(formCtx.fieldName, fieldValidators);
```

Reference - [Applying JSLink to list fields](https://www.martinhatch.com/2013/08/jslink-and-display-templates-part-1-overview-url-tokens-and-applying-jslink-to-objects.html)

[Introduction to Client forms validation](https://blog.vgrem.com/2014/03/14/introduction-to-client-forms-validation-in-sharepoint-2013/)

[Target audience not required](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c4ae0903-3a80-40f8-8367-b75c5b9c8af7/required-field-target-audiences-is-not-stopping-submit?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy)